# Is Vishwamitra also a creator of a new Universe like Brahma?

Tags: creation, vishwamitra

I have heard that Vishwamitra began creating different things. He created Sun, Moon, Stars, oceans, Rivers etc. As the result of his creations, every natural thing became double in number. one that had already been created by Brahma and the second created by Vishwamitra.

How could he able to create duplicate things?

Did he created anything new which is already not created by Brahma?

What happens to his creations?

Comment: @ Kailash Chandra
Polai i have even never come across such a story overall he is a brahmrishi and they are changed in every manavantara. Creation can be performed only by **tridevas or supreme god(both are same) may prajapatis as sage kashyapa can be referred but not sage vishwamitra. ;)** 

There is a diffrent heaven he created for trishanku but not all things.

Comment: Your question is partially right..when Indra refused to take Trishanku in heaven, Vishvamitra started creating another heaven and few other things too..this is in Ramayana and few Puranas..shall post an answer later..

Comment: @fiercelord _"Creation can be performed only by tridevas"_ Not true. Maya danava also did create three planets known as Tripura. When Evil works started on those planets and they intend to disturb solar system then Shiva came forward and Destroy all planets in one shot and got one more name, _Tripurari_. Point to note here is that he came forward only when they become thread to solar system, not before. So one can create whatever he want. Trideva never stops someone from creation.

Comment: @Rishabh I know this thats why after that i also written something and i was talking about whole creation not some particular thing.

Comment: Since trishanku had became chandala due to curse, in other side of universe(southern hemisphere, below equator, tamasic counterparts to aryan sattvic rajasic animals, like cow to buffalo, horse to donkey, pigeon to crow, were originated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, Vishwamitra did his own creation.** This is described in the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana.  The solar dynasty king Trishanku wanted to go to Swarga in his own body, so he asked the sage Vasishta to help him.  Vasishta refused, so Trishanku did a variety of bad things to Vasishta in response.  Vasishta was outraged and cursed Trishanku to become a Chandala.  But then the sage Vishwamitra decided to help Trishanku, out of hatred for Vasishta.  Vishwamitra performed a Yagna which sent Trishanku to Swarga in his own body. As soon as he arrived in Swarga, Indra threw him down from there.  But then Vishwamitra created a new Loka, called Trishanku Swarga, for Trishanku to rule over.  The Devas were concerned about this, and requested Vishwamitra not to allow a sinner like Trishanku to enjoy such prosperity.  Vishwamitra compromised with them and made Trishanku hang upside down in the Loka he had created, as described in [this chapter](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga60/bala_60_frame.htm) of the Bala Kanda of the Ramayana:

> Like the other Creator that resplendent Vishvamitra, himself staying among sages, has replicated Southerly Ursa Major in southerly direction. And still remaining amidst of sages that highly reputed sage Vishvamitra further started to replicate the stereotyped stocks of stars sequentially, resorting to the southern hemisphere, as he is convulsed in anger at Indra. On replicating the stereotyped stocks of other galaxies and stars, and while fury continued to blemish him Vishvamitra said, 'I will now clone an alternative Indra, or let that realm created by me remain without any Indra,' and when he is about to proceed to clone even gods in his wrath, the gods are startled.
>
> The gods are highly startled at Vishvamitra's creation, and they along with demons and with observances of hermits addressed the great-souled Vishvamitra with placatory words. 'Oh great-fortunate Vishvamitra, this king Trishnaku is damned by his mentor, hence oh, ascetically wealthy sage, he is not at all eligible to go to heaven with his mortal body.' So said gods to Vishvamitra. On hearing that sentence of those gods, the eminent saint Kaushika spoke this highly laudable sentence to all of the gods. 'Let safety betide you all. I have promised to this king Trishanku that he will ascend to heaven with his mortal body, and I am not interested to make it untrue. Let there be eternal heaven to Trishanku with his mortal body. Next, as along as the worlds remain, let all of these stars and galaxies I have created also remain eternally in their places as my creation. It will be apt of you all gods to accede to this.' So said Vishvamitra to gods.
>
> When all the gods are addressed thus they replied the eminent saint Vishvamitra saying, 'so be it! Safe you be! Let all the created objects prevail in their respective places. Those amazing and numerous stars you have created will remain in firmament, but outside the path of stelliform of Cosmic Person. Trishanku will also remain in the circle of stars you created, but upside-down, for Indra's indict cannot be annulled, and he will be gleaming like a star and similar to any celestial. According to their wont to circumambulate someone who has gone to heavenly worlds, all the stars will suppliantly circumambulate this best king Trishanku, who has achieved his ends and who has become an acclaimed one with your tour de force.' So said gods to Vishvamitra in deterring his further cloning of a simulative Universe. Even the benign-souled Vishvamitra, when reverenced by all gods, that great- resplendent sage without stirring himself from among the sages said to all gods, 'Agreed!'

In any case, the outcome of this compromise is that Trishanku Swarga is still there to this day.  Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trishanku) "Trishanku corresponds to the collection of three crosses around Crux, also known as the Southern Cross."  By the way, it's interesting that Trishanku Swarga is described as outside the "the path of stelliform of Cosmic Person" or Vaishvanara Patha, which I assume is the Milky Way. (By which I do not mean the entire galaxy, but the part of the galaxy that's visible as a colorful blur in the night sky in places with little light pollution.)

Comment: Are "Vaishvanara Patha" and "Aryaman Pantha" same?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I'm not sure about that.  Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryaman) that Aryaman Pantha is the Milky Way.  I've come across a couple references to Aryaman Pantha in the Vedas, but those passages don't specify what exactly it is.

Comment: Oh OK. We will look for these.

Answer (score 8):

The detail story of Rishi Vishwamitra creating  another new creation and a second Svargaloka (Heaven) is also can be found in
Book 7 - Chapter 14 - of  [**Devi Bhagavata Purana.**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57271.html)   Chapter Name -**"On the going to Heavens of Triśaṅku and the commencement of Hariścandra’s narrative".**

> **Background** - Once during  famine king Satyavrata ,on seeing poor condition of Rishi Vishwamitras family supplied them the food ,when
>   the rishi was engaged in Tapasya and was outside of his ashrama. One
>   day the king didn't got any food (meat) and he   slaughtered the
>   Kāma Dhenu (the cow giving all desires) of Vaśiṣṭha. Knowing this 
>   Rishi Vashistha became angry and on account of the killing of his cow,
>   called the King by the name of Triśaṅku and made him a Cāṇḍāla.  
>   Hearing about his help  Vishwamitra was pleased with Trishankand  decided to
>   free the King of his curse, The king also asked Vishwamitra  about a
>   way withwhich he can go to the Heavens in his  present body.
>   Vishwamitra then gave the King all the Puṇyams (merits) that he
>   collected for himself. Thus by virtue of the Muni’s Tapas "Trishanku
>   went up in the heaven.

When Trishanku reached heaven ,the gods seeing him thus spoke to Indra.

> 9-20 Thus getting up and up, when the King reached the abode of Indra,
>   the Devas, seeing the terrible Cāṇḍāla-like appearance of Triśaṅku,
>   spoke out to Indra :-- “Who is this person coming like a Deva with a
>   violent speed in the air? Why does he look like a Cāṇḍāla.

Indra disliking Trishankus  presence in Swarga loka again dropped him on earth.

> Indra said - You are a Cāṇḍāla, quite unfit for the Devaloka; so where
>   are you going? You ought not to remain here; so go immediately back to
>   the earth. O Destroyer of the enemies! Indra speaking thus, the King
>   dropped from the Heavens and, like a Deva whose merits had been
>   exhausted, fell down immediately.

While coming back to earth from heaven Triśaṅku cried and said to Vishwamitra.

> “O Viśvāmitra! O Viśvāmitra! Being displaced from the Heavens I am now
>   falling very violently; so save me from this trouble.”

Upon hearing his cry and seeing him getting down, Viśvāmitra by virtue of the  Tapas kept stationed him in midway. And started creating new creation.

> O King! Hearing his cry and seeing him getting down, Viśvāmitra said
>   :-- “Wait, wait.” Though displaced from Heaven, the King by virtue of
>   the Muni’s Tapas, remained stationed at that place in the middle of
>   the air. **Viśvāmitra then began to do Ācaman (sip water) and
>   commenced his great Sacrifice to create another new creation and a
>   second Svargaloka (Heaven).**

Seeing his resolve Indra  became very anxious and came down to Vishwamitra and said to Vishwamitra."There is no necessity to create another new creation".But Vishwamitra was determined one. And asked Indra to take Trishanku in his own abode.
Indra accepted that

> 22-31 Vyāsa said :-- O King! Indra was thoroughly aware of his
>   determined resolve and very powerful asceticism; so he accepted to do
>   according to his word, out of terror. The Lord Indra then gave the
>   King a bright and divine body and made him take his seat in an
>   excellent car and taking leave of Kauśika went with the King to his
>   own abode.

So there is not much info. here in this purana about What happens to his creation.But it's clear that Vishwamitra through his merit (Tapas) created different creation i.e. Grahas ,Nakshatras ,lokas etc. including Swarga loka (Heaven).

---

The description of Sage  Vishvamitra creating another creation is also there in **Skanda Purana Book VI - Nagar Kanda - Chapters 2-7.**
Here we can see the every detail of his creation in Chapter seven.

> ॥ सूत उवाच ॥ ॥ एवं ध्यायमानेन जलमाविश्य काम्यया ॥
>  सृष्टं
>   संध्याद्वयं तच्च दृश्यतेऽद्यापि वै द्विजाः ॥ 1 ॥
>
> 1 Suta said - witha keen desire , he entered water and began to
>   meditate. Then he created **two sandhya's** (twilights). O Brahmmanas they
>   are to be  seen even today.
>
> ---
>
> ततो देवगणाः सर्वे सृष्टास्तेन
>   महात्मना ॥
>  वैमानिकाश्च ये केचिन्नक्षत्राणि ग्रहास्तथा ॥ 2॥
>   मनुष्योरगरक्षांसि वीरुधो वृक्षसंयुताः ॥
>  सप्तर्षयो ध्रुवाद्याश्च ये
>   चान्ये गगनेचराः ॥ 3॥
>  एवं हि भगवान्सृष्ट्वा विश्वामित्रः स
>   मन्युमान् ॥
>
> 2-3 Thereafter all the **groups of devas were created by
>   that nobel-souled one. Persons travelling in aerial chariots ,stars
>   and planets , human beings ,serpants and Rakshasas ,creepers and
>   trees; the seven sages (Great Bear) ,dhruva and others (pole star
>   etc.).And sky walkers were created.**

---

> स्वकीयेष्वथ कृत्येषु योजयामास तांस्ततः ॥ 4 ॥
>  एतस्मिन्नेव काले तु
>   द्वौ सूर्यो युगपद्दिवि ॥
>  उदितौ रात्रिनाथौ च जाताश्च द्विगुणा
>   ग्रहाः ॥
>  द्विगुणानि च भान्येव सह सप्तर्षिभिर्द्विजाः ॥ 5॥
>
> 4-5 After creating  these , the angry sage Visvamitra employed them in
>   his own work **At that time two suns and two moons rose up in the sky
>   simultaneously.** There were two set of planets.Two sets of stars along
>   with the great bear came up , O Brahmanas.
>
> एवं वियति ते सर्वे स्पर्द्धमानाः परस्परम् ॥ दृश्यंते द्विगुणीभूता
>   जनविभ्रमकारकाः ॥ 6॥
>
> 6 Thus **they competed with one another** and were seen doubled causing
>   chaos and confusion in the minds of the people

---

Then Lord  Brahma assured Vishwamitra that your creation will stay as it is , but they will never be eligible to share YAJNA and other rites.

> भविष्यति ध्रुवा विप्र सृष्टिर्या भवता कृता ॥
>  परं सर्वेषु कृत्येषु
>   यज्ञार्हा न भविष्यति ॥ 18 ॥
>
> 18 O Brahmana , what has been already created by you shall certainly
>   come to stay. But they will never  be eligible to share yajna and
>   other rites.
>
> ---
>
> [image]

Comment: Wow two suns rising together? Never heard of this.

Answer (score 7):

**How could Vishwamitra able to create duplicate things?**

Due to the boon given by Lord Shiva, he got the power of creation. This is described in the chapter named ***Vishwamitra Commences New Creation in Nagar Khand of Skanda Purana***:

[image]

*English Translation ([Source](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/skanda_purana/vishwamitra_commences_new_creation.html)):*

> Vishwamitra decided to please Lord Shiva as he was convinced that Shiva was the only deity who could help him achieve his goal. He eulogized Shiva by singing hymns of praise in his name. At last, Shiva appeared before him and expressed his desire of fulfilling any wish of Vishwamitra. Vishwamitra requested Shiva to bestow on him the power of creation. Lord Shiva blessed him and disappeared.

---

**Is Vishwamitra also a creator of a new Universe like Brahma?**

Not complete Universe but he created few things. At the end, Lord Bhrahma and/or Devas stopped him.

As per ***Sarga 60 of Balakanda of Valmiki Ramayana***:

[image]
[image]
[image]

*English Translation* ([Source 1](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga60/bala_60_frame.htm) & [Source 2](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=60)):

> Standing in the midst of the ascetics, that mighty sage who conjured up a constellation of seven new rishis (stars) looked like another creator Brahma. Overcome by anger the illustrious sage created a new group of stars in the southern direction.
>
> Having created a constellation of stars, Viswamitra out of anger said,
>   "I will create another Indra or this world will be without Indra" and
>   commenced to create even gods.

---

**Did he create anything new which is already not created by Brahma?**

Probably no thats why the word duplicate is used in most of the sources.

---

**What happened to his creations?**

As per ***Sarga 60 of Balakanda of Valmiki Ramayana***:

[image]
[image]

*English Translation* ([Source 1](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga60/bala_60_frame.htm) & [Source 2](https://www.valmiki.iitk.ac.in/sloka?field_kanda_tid=1&language=dv&field_sarga_value=60)):

> 'Let there be eternal heaven to Trishanku with his mortal body. Next, as along as the worlds remain, let all of these stars and galaxies I have created also remain eternally in their places as my creation. It will be apt of you all gods to accede to this.' So said Vishvamitra to gods.
>
> When all the gods are addressed thus they replied the eminent saint
>   Vishvamitra saying, 'so be it! Safe you be! Let all the created
>   objects prevail in their respective places. Those amazing and numerous
>   stars you have created will remain in firmament, but outside the path
>   of stelliform of Cosmic Person. Trishanku will also remain in the
>   circle of stars you created, but upside-down, for Indra's indict
>   cannot be annulled, and he will be gleaming like a star and similar to
>   any celestial.

Also this Bhasya from [this Source](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga60/bala_60_frame.htm) seems to be useful:

> Ursa Major is a prominent constellation in the northern sky, containing seven bright stars in a pattern variously called the Plough, the Big Dipper, or Charles's Wain. Also called Great Bear. In Latin it is, Ursa= greater (she-) bear. The Indian name to this is: sapta R^ishi maNDala Hence Vishvamitra adopted the opposite direction, namely southern direction, for his Creation, which shall be in direct opposition to the natural creation adopted by Almighty. From this point onwards, anything artificially or synthetically created, cloned, or replicated from natural item acquired the name of vishvaamitra SR^iSTi 'Vishvamitra's cloning,' including the present day hybrids. Whether this Ursa Major like constellation is still available in southern hemisphere - is a point left to astronomers, or stargazers.
>
> **Trishanku - and his universe**:
>
> Trishanku is the son of one Suuryaaruna and his original name is
>   Satyavrat and this name Trishanku is his pseudonym. He got this
>   because three sins are attached to him tri shanka-s as said in another
>   work Harivamsha. There it is said: pituH shaapa aadi doShena | guru
>   dogdhre vadhena ca | a-prokShito prayogaat ca | trividhaa tat
>   vyatikramaH | evam triiNi asya shankuuni | One by his father's
>   damnation - when he misbehaved in his kingdom, his father being a
>   righteous king exiles him to a wretched place. When his father was
>   exiling him, Trishanku took umbrage at Vashishta, because Vashishta
>   did not come to his rescue. The second blemish is due to the killing
>   Vashishta's milch cow, knowingly. Trishanku kills that cow, when he
>   did not get any food for the day to feed the son of Vishvamitra. At
>   that time, he had to protect the wife and three sons of Vishvamitra,
>   as Vishvamitra has gone away to a distant place for his ascesis,
>   leaving his kingdom and family. Then Trishanku comes to the rescue of
>   hs family. With that gratitude, now Vishvamitra tries to requite this
>   king in sending him to heaven. The third damnation is for his usage of
>   unsanctified meat of his kill. Thus, Trishanku is the one who carries
>   'three social blemishes' on his head, and added to these is the curse
>   of Vashishta, in making him as a profaner.
>
> Further, a god or teacher cannot be dragged to one's side or his
>   wishful thinking, but they are to be attained or appeased with
>   constant faith and servitude. guroH aliika nirbandho na kartavyaH
>   kadaacana | anumaanya prasaaH ca guru kruddho yudhiShTara | shiShyo
>   gurau narashreShTa pratikuulam na sa~ncaret | viShNu puraaNa And if
>   god created the cosmos, a man trying to duplicating it, is as good as
>   going against that writ of that god. Vishvamitra no doubt built many
>   space stations and started cloning gods, leave alone earthly species,
>   but he is forestalled, because he wanted to break the system from
>   within, in which he is and by which he mastered all this expertise. It
>   is as good as cutting the branch of a tree on which he is sitting.
>   Absolute insolence is absolutely condemnable. Hence, Trishanku is
>   still dangling upside down in his so-called heaven.

Comment: Nice described...and a good answer Thanks for your efforts