# Where does Vishwamitra's parallel creation of constellations of stars and galaxies exist?

Tags: ramayana, creation, vishwamitra, swarga

From my answer to a previous question, it was pointed out that Vishwamitra himself attempted to create a parallel world in addition to Brahma's, in which to transport Trisanku in his mortal body.

> svargo astu sa shariirasya trisha.nkoH asya shaashvataH |
>   nakSatraaNi ca sarvaaNi maamakaani dhruvaaNi atha || 1-60-28
>   yaavat lokaa dhariSyanti tiSThanti etaani sarvashaH |
>  yat kRitaani
>   suraaH sarve tat anuj~naatum arhatha || 1-60-29
>
> "'Let there be eternal heaven to Trishanku with his mortal body. Next,
>   as along as the worlds remain, **let all of these stars and galaxies I
>   have created also remain eternally in their places as my creation.**
>   It will be apt of you all gods to accede to this.' So said Vishwamitra
>   to gods.
>
> evam uktaaH suraaH sarve prati uucuH muni pu.ngavam | 
>  evam
>   bhavatu bhadram te tiSThantu etaani sarvashaH || 1-60-30
>  gagane
>   taani anekaani vaishvaanara pathaat bahiH |
>  nakSatraaNi muni
>   shreSTha teSu jyotiHSu jaajvalan || 1-60-31
>  avaag shiraaH
>   trishankuH ca tiSThatu amara sannibhaH |
>
> "When all the gods are addressed thus they replied the eminent saint
>   Vishwamitra saying, 'so be it! Safe you be! Let all the created
>   objects prevail in their respective places. Those amazing and numerous
>   stars you have created will remain in firmament, but outside the path
>   of stelliform of Cosmic Person. **Trishanku will also remain in the
>   circle of stars you created**, but upside-down, for Indra's indict
>   cannot be annulled, and he will be gleaming like a star and similar to
>   any celestial.

Brahma's creation can be more or less mapped to scientific accounts of the material world, through careful and minute Shastra analysis. However, my question is, which physical body/bodies represent Vishwamitra's parallel creation, which were destined to "remain eternally in their places"? Assuming they do exist, is it even known to us, where they currently are, and which ones they are? I don't require parallels with modern science. Are there any names of these bodies, mentioned in Shastras?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Vishwamitra also a creator of a new Universe like Brahma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/is-vishwamitra-also-a-creator-of-a-new-universe-like-brahma)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma  ... sorry I had clicked the approve button by mistake, I re-edited the Q.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria ... above comment.

Comment: "I don't require parallels with modern science. Are there any names of these bodies, mentioned in Shastras?" - and yet you have accepted as answer which is highly speculative and deals more with science than Śāstras.

Comment: He has given me the verse in Ramayana. So if I didn't accept the answer just because he has given me scientific references, wouldn't it be pretty cheap? Plus it does outline a bit more. Just sufficient enough for my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the Ramayana gives a bit more detail about the possible location of the creation of Vishwamitra. According to the **[Bala Kanda of the Valmiki Ramayan](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga60/bala_60_frame.htm)**:

> "Like the other Creator that resplendent Vishvamitra, himself staying among sages, has replicated **Southerly Ursa Major in southerly direction.** And still remaining amidst of sages that highly reputed sage Vishvamitra **further started to replicate the stereotyped stocks of stars sequentially, resorting to the southern hemisphere,** as he is convulsed in anger at Indra.
>
> On replicating the stereotyped stocks of other galaxies and stars, and while fury continued to blemish him Vishvamitra said, 'I will now clone an alternative Indra, or let that realm created by me remain without any Indra,' and when he is about to proceed to clone even gods in his wrath, the gods are startled. The gods are highly startled at Vishvamitra's creation, and they along with demons and with observances of hermits addressed the great-souled Vishvamitra with placatory words.

Though these verses don't exactly tell us the name of the constellation but it does tell us that it is perhaps **similar to the Ursa Major or Saptarishi and exists in the Southern Hemisphere.** If you know a bit about the astronomical chart, there is a constellation known as the **[Crux or Southern Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crux)** which was used for navigation by sailors much like the Saptarishi helps in pointing to the Pole Star or Polaris that we know as the Dhruv Tara.

[image]

[image]

As mentioned by the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crux) page on Crux:

> In the Southern Hemisphere, the Southern Cross is frequently used for navigation in much the same way that Polaris is used in the Northern Hemisphere. Alpha and Gamma (known as Acrux and Gacrux respectively) are commonly used to mark south. Tracing a line from Gacrux to Acrux leads to a point close to the Southern Celestial Pole.

Both the constellations of Saptarishi and Trishanku therefore serve a similar purpose of guiding towards the poles in their respective hemispheres. The wikipedia page for [Trishanku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trishanku) also mentions that Trishanku corresponds to the collection of three crosses around Crux, also known as the Southern Cross based on a page on Astronomy. **So this seems to be the most likely candidate given the little information we have.**

And just to add a bit of science, these are not just five stars rather these are star systems that are about 10-20 million years old. As per this [constellation guide](http://www.constellation-guide.com/the-southern-cross/):

> The stars of the Southern Cross – Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta, and Epsilon Crucis – form an asterism that really looks more like a kite than a cross. The stars Alpha, Beta and Delta Crucis are co-moving members of the Scorpius-Centaurus Association, a young association of stars in the constellations Scorpius and Centaurus that belong to the spectral class O and B, have common proper motion, and **are believed to have formed inside the same giant molecular cloud.**

[image]

> α Crucis (Alpha Crucis), also known as Acrux or HD 108248, is a bluish star that marks the bottom of the Southern Cross when you are facing south. It is the brightest star in the constellation Crux. **It is really a multiple star system** with a combined apparent magnitude of 0.77, making Acrux the 13th brightest star in the night sky.

As you may be aware the constellations that we see from the earth are not actually located in the same pattern. The different stars of these apparently identifiable shapes are sometimes located thousands of light years away and are completely unrelated to each other.

However, as mentioned in the above excerpt, **if the principal stars of the Crux emerged from the same cloud of stardust it is likely that were created at the same time** which kind of supports Vishwamitra's hand in it.

Comment: Yup, actually my interest in astronomy has led me to ask this question. I am aware of the star charts you've posted here, and thank you for a nice comprehensive answer. Crux by far looks like the most identifiable pattern with no comprehensive mythology (story) as far as ancient Greece is concerned. They regarded it as part of the constellation Centaurus. Indeed there are many celestial metric changes which were caused and effected by the high yogic intervention of people from Bharatvarsha. The Cosmos is not only for the Greeks. :)

Comment: Again I don't know because as far as Ancient Greece is concerned, Ptolemy regarded them as part of the constellation Centaurus. Ptolemy was not exactly a "seer" so his words might not have cosmic significance. Had it been Greek shamans, or seers, their words would have been more trustworthy than Ptolemy.

Comment: Indeed a good answer.

Comment: Thanks! I did a lot of research on this for my book on Vishwamitra so I guess that has come in handy here! BTW as mentioned above in the excerpt from the constellation guide they are indeed located in the vicinity of scorpio and centaurus so maybe the Greeks were not very wrong.

Comment: Yes, your answer was worth reading. Even I got a hint of tracing the observational/mythological origins of the Crux-Scorpius-Centaurus group of constellations, right up to the Big Dipper. As far as I know Orion and Scorpius were placed in the opposite ends of the world so as to stop them from fighting. Orion has a lot of Greek myths and legends. But as far as transforming mortals to stars go, I guess both Greek and Vedic [and other] (demi)gods contributed to the same.

Comment: And all the best for your book! My sincere prayers and good wishes for it :)

Comment: Also, regarding the Centaurus part, I am not saying Ptolemy was wrong. I mean, they might not have heard any Greek myths for Crux, so he just assumed it to be a part of Centaurus. Its true that they are in close vicinity of each other.

Comment: Yes I got your point! Thanks a lot for your wishes :)