# Do scriptures mention of rishis, who have the power to create fully grown human beings?

Tags: scripture, vedas, rishi, siddhi

Do scriptures mention of rishis, who could create fully grown human beings using their power?

Comment: As per https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23185/12304 post, Vishwamitra had such power given by Lord Shiva...

Answer (score 0):

The birth of Dhrishtadyumna and Draupadi is indicative of ascetic power of Rishies, who can make human take birth in full grown shape.

Drupada, after getting a humiliated defeat in a war with Arjuna and after Drona's snatching away half of his kingdom, [decides to obtain a warrior son](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01170.htm),who can kill Drona and a daughter, who can marry Arjuna, through a Yajna.

We have to remember that till then Sikhandi, a woman turned male, was the only child that Drupada had.

> Then king Drupada, impelled by the desire of obtaining a son who was
> to slay Drona, began, for the success of his wish, to make the
> necessary preparations. (And when everything was complete) Yaja, after
> having poured libations of clarified butter on the sacrificial fire,
> commanded Drupada's queen, saying, 'Come hither, O queen, O
> daughter-in-law of Prishata! A son and a daughter have arrived for
> thee!'
>
> Hearing this, the queen said, 'O Brahmana, my mouth is yet filled with
> saffron and other perfumed things. My body also beareth many sweet
> scents; I am hardly fit for accepting (the sanctified butter which is
> to give me offspring). Wait for me a little, O Yaja! Wait for that
> happy consummation.'
>
> Yaja, however, replied, 'O lady, whether thou comest or waitest, why
> should not the object of this sacrifice be accomplished when the
> oblation hath already been prepared by me and sanctified by Upayaja's
> invocations?'
>
> "The Brahmana continued, 'Having said this, Yaja poured the sanctified
> libation on the fire, whereupon arose from those flames a child
> resembling a celestial who possessing the effulgence of fire, was
> terrible to behold. With a crown on this head and his body encased in
> excellent armour, sword in hand, and bearing a bow and arrows, he
> frequently sent forth loud roars. And immediately after his birth, he
> ascended an excellent chariot and went about in it for some time. Then
> the Panchalas in great joy shouted, 'Excellent, Excellent.'
>
> The very earth seemed at that time unable to bear the weight of the
> Panchalas mad with joy. Then, marvellous to say, the voice of some
> invisible spirit in the skies said, 'This prince hath been born for
> the destruction of Drona. He shall dispel all the fears of the
> Panchalas and spread their fame. He shall also remove the sorrow of
> the king.'
>
> And there arose, after this from the centre of the sacrificial
> platform, a daughter also, called Panchali, who, blest with great good
> fortune, was exceedingly handsome. Her eyes were black, and large as
> lotus-petals, her complexion was dark, and her locks were blue and
> curly. Her nails were beautifully convex, and bright as burnished
> copper; her eye-brows were fair, and bosom was deep. Indeed, she
> resembled the veritable daughter of a celestial born among men.
>
> Her body gave out fragrance like that of a blue lotus, perceivable
> from a distance of full two miles. Her beauty was such that she had no
> equal on earth. Like a celestial herself, she could be desired (in
> marriage) by a celestial, a Danava, or a: Yaksha. When this girl of
> fair hips was born an incorporeal voice said, 'This dark-complexioned
> girl will be the first of all women, and she will be the cause of the
> destruction of many Kshatriyas.
>
> This slender-waisted one will, in time, accomplish the purpose of the
> gods, and along with her many a danger will overtake the Kauravas.' On
> hearing these words, the Panchalas uttered a loud leonine roar, and
> the earth was unable to bear the weight of that joyous concourse. Then
> beholding the boy and the girl, the daughter-in-law of Prishata,
> desiring to have them, approached Yaja and said, 'Let not these know
> any one else except myself as their mother.' Yaja, desiring to do good
> unto the king said, 'So be it!'
>
> Then the Brahmanas (present there), their expectations fully
> gratified, bestowed names upon the new-born pair, 'Let this son of
> king Drupada, they said, be called ***Dhrishtadyumna***, because of
> his excessive audacity and because of his being born like ***Dyumna***
> with a natural mail and weapon.' And they also said, 'Because this
> daughter is so dark in complexion, she should be called **Krishna**
> (the dark).'