# Hinduism Stories Of Creating A Fully Grown New Person (Like Draupadi)

Tags: life, birth

Aside from Draupadi and her twin brother brought about by Drupad yagya in Mahabharath, what are the other stories in Hindu religious texts and Puran where a fully grown new person is created ?

I think there are several instances, can’t recall exactly which texts have them.

Came across a few posts on here discussing this topic in past threads but can’t find them now. The basic premise is that a fully grown new person is brought about by yagya/tap/vardaan. Any info greatly appreciated :D

(Not talking about danav/daitya kul, where the santaan grow up very quickly within days to be an adult. More just normal people. Thx !)

Comment: Came across another question like this : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/42716/do-scriptures-mention-of-rishis-who-have-the-power-to-create-fully-grown-human