# Do deities other than Brahma, Vishnu, Devi etc. have the power to create other universes?

Tags: scripture, puranas, gods, philosophy, goddess

I am aware that in many Hindu texts, famously the Puranas, explained that the gods Brahma creates universes constantly, Vishnu constantly creates universes by inhaling and exhaling also infinite universes are constantly coming out of his body pores, and that the goddess Devi hold the title of ***Anekakotibrahmandajanani*** *(One who gives birth to millions of universes.)*

Are there any other gods that have the power to do so, or is this power only limited to those three?

Comment: [do](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19033/22556) this answers your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Vedic verses describe Indra as Brahman?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/which-vedic-verses-describe-indra-as-brahman)

Comment: @DarkKnight That doesn't really answer his question. Indra is not shown anywhere in Hindu scripture to create universes or even have the power to create them. Calling Indra "Brahman" doesn't prove it either since scripture calls everything Brahman. To answer this question, you have to provide verses that explicitly show Indra creating universes.

Comment: Well, this is more of a question of Ifs and Buts. Using analogy, one may arrive at some definitive but not authoritative conclusions. For example Vishwãmitra (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23179/17833) creating new firmaments is found. Similarly, one may conclude that with enough Spiritual Merit and Sadhnã done (tapascharya - तपश्चर्या, and साधना ), any being can acquire such kinds of power to Create. How many have done it as per scriptures or is it even allowed though, remains another question perhaps!

Comment: @Ikshvaku Let us praise him who made these worlds and creatures, all things that after him sprang into being. May we win Mitra with our songs, and Indra, and. wait upon our Lord with adoration. (RigVeda 8.85.6) this verse says that Indra made these worlds and creatures

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Vishwamitra also a creator of a new Universe like Brahma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/is-vishwamitra-also-a-creator-of-a-new-universe-like-brahma)

Comment: @DarkKnight I mean scriptures even describe Vamadeva, Prahlada, etc. as creating universes and being Brahman themselves. These verses are attributing qualities of Brahman to everyone to convey the idea that Brahman is behind everything. There has to be much more specific verses, like Vishvamitra's story of creating a new heaven for Trishanku.

Comment: @Ikshvaku All the texts I've read describe infinite universes existing, but they are conflicted on who creates them, some say Brahma, others Vishnu, so would the deity who creates them differ from sect to sect?